# Advice on building fast real-time deep learning application

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I am attempting to build my first real-time deep learning application that recognises license plates. I already have all the building blocks like detection, segmentation and recognition in place and is able to perform those tasks individually.

During real-time camera feed, I found that it is impractical to just connect all these tasks as every single task would take some time to complete and the end result is rather laggy.

For example, in the snippet below, there are 3 main tasks and each task would take 0.1-1.5 seconds to complete and each task must complete before proceeding to the next one. This way, the live stream wouldn't immediately load the next frame and this leaves me very awkward.

I tried to allocate these tasks to pool workers so that the live video feed wouldn't look so choppy but the results are not significant. I also tried to create dedicated pools and queues for different tasks but the results are disappointing.

I am running this on a relatively powerful machine and I understood this is a design problem. Can anyone guide me on the proper way to build a fast and non-blocking real-time deep learning system? Any help would be appreciated!

```
import cv2
from imutils import resize
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, cpu_count

def worker(inQueue, outQueue):
    while True:
        image = inQueue.get()
        # detection
        # segmentation
        # recognition
        outQueue.put(result)

inQueue, outQueue = Queue(maxsize=8), Queue(maxsize=8)
pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count(), initializer=self.worker, initargs=(inQueue, outQueue))

vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    if frame is not None:
        frame = resize(frame, 800)

        inQueue.put(frame)

        # get result
        print(outQueue.get())

        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one problem is that you wait for the results:

```
    inQueue.put(frame)
    # get result
    print(outQueue.get())
```

This will put the frame into the queue then wait for the result. No parallel processing is going on.

A simple fix would be to have two loops:

```
def InputThread(inQueue):
  vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

  while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    if frame is not None:
      frame = resize(frame, 800)
      inQueue.put(frame)
      cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

def OutputThread(outQueue):
    print(outQueue.get())
```

You run each of them in a thread. One will en-queue frames as you get them and the other will display processed frames. Now, this will run in parallel and may cause other problems.

One thing is that the output frames might get shuffled (one frame might process faster than another and return results first). You might want to attach some id/counter so that you can put them in the right order.

There might be more gains to be had in how you handle your models, but I can't say much since they are not part of your example.